# The emulator isn't showing the XML contents

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I have been reading [Google's android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html) and I got a problem...
 In the tutorial they explain the XML elements (EditText and Button) and in the end they say how to tun the program to see the button + the text field.
The problem is, that the emulator doesn't show them.. just a black screen.
I even tried adding this line to the onCreate function -

```
System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

but still the emulator is showing only black screen..
Here's the .java main file - http://pastebin.com/G5J9YjNe

And the XML files (I mentioned what code is what file) - http://pastebin.com/VnRwAfMW

What should I do?

Thanks **a lot** for everyone who will help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

does not print any thing on screen. it can seen on Consol. i tried below code and working fine for me.

//     Main Activity
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.kuchbhi);
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
```

Layout /.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/text_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="enter text" />

    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Manifest file ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

try this code and let me know what u see.

I tried your source code and it is working fine for me. see screen

[image: your app screen]